# Integral for spherical wave propagation through lens

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How do I perform this integral?

```
g3[a_, b_] = 
Assuming[Element[{a, b}, Reals] && (Abs[a] > 0 || Abs[b] > 0) && 
r > 0, Integrate[
Exp[I*k*(p^2 + q^2)^(1/2)]/((p^2 + q^2)^(1/2))*Exp[I*(a*p + b*q)],
Element[{p, q}, Disk[{0, 0}, r]]] // FunctionExpand]
```